# HTML/TVML not showing picture?

Tags: javascript, html, tvos, tvml

So I have made a little app, guided by this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/114886/beginning-tvos-development-with-tvml-tutorial

I've got a few items in my grid, but somehow the images are not shown. I've got the images on my desc, client/images/ray.png for example.

I tried it with ../images/ray.png or ray.png or ../ray.png or /ray.png. dunno what is wrong with that. The whole path file:///....../client/images/ray.png is not working either

```
 <lockup videoURL="... .mp4">
 <img src="${this.BASEURL}images/ray.png" width="500" height="308" /> 
 <title>Itemtitle</title>
 </lockup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by myself: I've got an Apple TV instead of a xcode simulator, means I can't execute just local files. Instead I had to use my IP address to get to my files.

Example :

```
<img src="http://your ip adress/images/testimage.png" width="500" height="308" />
```